# Can I Unlink a Firebase user account in this scenario?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I read the [Firebase User Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#unlink) and the [Firebase  anonymous auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)  and see there is an `Unlink`
method on the User like:

> unlink ( providerId :  string ) : Promise < User >

Is this possible to do even user is only signed in using one prover like Google?

How does this work if user first is signed in Anonymously then linked to Facebook or Google provider?

Comment: Why do you need to unlink the only provider on an account?  That would mean the user of the account can no longer sign in at all, as there is no provider to validate their identity.

Comment: Thanks Doug I just learn this now, what about User first sign in Anonymously and then upgrade/link to a Google provider? Removing Google here what happens?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.  As I suggested in my first comment, I don't know why you would want to do this.